# c# SelectedIndex error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to use the following code

```
 update_facility_shift_duration.SelectedIndex = Int32.Parse(reader_facility["facility_shift_duration_id"].ToString()); //If this is current user's facility add select
```

`update_facility_shift_duration` is the ID for the  `<selected>` which gets its value by the following code

```
update_facility_shift_duration.Items.Add(new ListItem(result, reader_facility["facility_shift_duration_id"].ToString()));
```

I have about 6 select options and want to select the one that matches the ID in the database .

But I am getting the following error. Does anyone know how to solve this or might have some idea to push me in the right direction? 
Thanks in advance

[image: Error]

Comment: Do you have any means to verify the contents of facility_shift_duration_id? It looks like it's trying to find something in reader_facility[] that does not exist

Comment: Are you initializing your items collection in `Page_Init`? This might be crucial if you want to work with a client-provided selected index in `Page_Load`.

Comment: Please check `update_facility_shift_duration.Items.Count` before assigning the `SelectedIndex`. Make sure there are enough items.

Comment: @grek40 'ListItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'ListItemCollection' could be found

Comment: Ok, I actually don't know the type of `update_facility_shift_duration` but do whatever you must in order to verify the current item count.

Comment: @grek40 I can't seem to get that Count() working. I'm not sure if its relevant but if i comment the code that results into that error and load the page without it there are 6 options avaible in the dropdown.

Comment: Noone said anything about `Count()` as a method. Try `Count` as a property.

Comment: @grek40 Ah my bad, I get the following result : 22

Answer (score 1):

reader_facility["facility_shift_duration_id"] is probably null. Check it is null or empty.

Comment: Yeah If I `Response.Write(reader_facility["facility_shift_duration_id"].ToString());` It is populated with a `2`

Comment: You are setting ListItem value as facility_shift_duration_id. Then you are trying to find this item from index but you are giving value which is your id. Try selectedValue instead of selectedIndex.

Comment: I get the following message if I try that : 'htmlSelect' does not contain a definition 'selectedValue' and no extension method 'selectedValue' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlSelect' could be found.

Comment: @RickStandaert you gotta keep your brain running while you try suggestions from Stackoverflow. There is no `selectedValue` but there is a `SelectedValue` and you are expected to find these little variations yourself if someone suggests to try `selectedValue`!

Comment: @grek40 I also tried SelectedValue with captitals an tried different variations, I get the same message except the name is sometimes spelled with a capital and sometimes without

Comment: @RickStandaert Just to be sure... are we both talking about `update_facility_shift_duration.SelectedValue` and is `update_facility_shift_duration` some sort of [`ListControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx)? (If not, what is it?)

Comment: @grek40 It is a hardcoded `<select name="update_facility_shift_duration" id="update_facility_shift_duration" class="form-control" required runat="server"></select>` which is populated by the following code `update_facility_shift_duration.Items.Add(new ListItem(result, reader_facility["facility_shift_duration_id"].ToString()));` This code is written above `update_facility_shift_duration.SelectedIndex` but still within the same While read loop.

Comment: @RickStandaert ah, makes sense... then it's presumably [`value` instead of `selectedValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms535893(vs.85).aspx#properties)